# How to create a symbol in EAGLE that consists of multiple other symbols?

Tags: eaglecad, packages, symbol

I'm trying to create a symbol that consists of multiple other symbols. I'd like it to look similar to what's in [this datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/84303/vor2142b8.pdf).

I have found out how to create the part itself, but i'm not sure if I can use the MOSFET symbols combined with diode symbols to create the symbol for this part. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You just draw them with basic tools.

Comment: When drawing the symbol, just use the line tools. Change the grid size and line width as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- there's a package and there's a symbol. Package exists to connect pads on the board with conductive tracks, symbol on schematic exists to present, in *human readable* format, the sense of the connections. I saw many times people using package-like symbols on schematics, and it is not a right way - it creates messy circuit diagrams which are hard to read. My advice: do not draw *symbol* as it is shown in this datasheet;
- then, you can see there're two identical *functionally* independent pieces in this package. You should create a symbol for one of them, and then, at device level, add two of them to the device, and then assign package and pins to pads of the symbol;
- there's a trick. I am sure there's LED symbol already existing in DIODE library, and I am sure there's MOSFET existing in some other library. You do not need to reinvent bicycle, your task is to copy-paste their symbols into newly created symbol, and ensure pins are named properly, and symbol in overall looks properly and is human-readable.

You may find [this article](http://kb.gr8bit.ru/KB0015/GR8BIT-KB0015-Best-practices-creating-designs-with-EAGLE.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not wanting to create a symbol constisting of multiple symbols. You want to create a device with a single symbol (for the schematic) which has multiple footprints.

A device is the overarching component. VOR2142A8 in this case.
A symbol is the schematical representation of the connections. These are A1, C1, V1, O1 and A2, C2, V2, and O2.
A footprint are the pads or holes on the physical PCB itself. You have two packages here SMD-8 and DIP-8.

Create a symbol with all the io pins (name it something like VOR2142). Create the two packages (or take some premade ones from somewhere) (Name these SMD-8 and DIP-8). Create a device called VOR2142A. Add the symbol and footprints and then connect the pins from the symbol to the packages. Now you'll be able to add two variants of this device in the schematic editor.